# Сгенерировать для Insert значение timestamp

Tags: mysql

Как сгенерировать автоматически для **Insert** значение **timestamp** в формате: 1412799134?

Comment: Есть магические константы и функции `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `CURRENT_DATE`, а также функции `CURDATE()`, `CURTIME()`, `NOW()`. Из всего это зоопарка в MySQL в качестве значения по умолчанию устанавливается только `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, но этого должно хватить на любые типы данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто в базе тип поля установи TIMESTAMP, и оно атоматом будет проставлять.

Comment: Если тип TIMESTAMP, то формат данных : 2014-10-21 02:25:33, а мне нужен TIMESTMAP в секундах.

Comment: Тогда тип поля ставь просто int и перед записью даты делай strtotime().

Comment: А почему бы не использовать **UNIX_TIMESTAMP()**?

Comment: Я написал, как я это делал бы, думаю, есть еще много разных вариантов.

Comment: Если тип данных TIMESTAMP, то это и есть время в секундах, а то что в phpmyadmin (или еще где-то) вы видите 2014-10-21 02:25:33, то это сама прога преобразует в удобочитаемый формат